# How to fix wordpress main domain keeps redirecting to subdomain

Tags: wordpress, redirect

WordPress main domain keeps redirecting to my subdomain

tried adding `define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://example.com' ); define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com' );`

and tried updating the wp_options

anyone can help ?

Comment: are you running multisite/network? I have the following as well in my config
`
    define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
    define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'https://example.com');
    define('MULTISITE', true);
    define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
    define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
`

Comment: @BarrieDawson no I'm not running multisite, and 100% checked the redirect on cpanel

Comment: What is in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: How are you testing?  Have you cleared your browser cache?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I tried deleting the .htaccess still redirecting, also tried clearing the browser cache